# accessing children with attributes with simplexml...how?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, simplexml

I'm trying to access specific parts of a XML file with PHP (simplexml) without looping through. I just want to access a specific field. But how? This is the structure of the xml file:

```
<collection xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
    <record>
        <datafield tag="010" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">96174405</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">(OCoLC)ocm34158924</subfield>
        </datafield>
    </record>
</collection>
```

For example, how would I print 96174405?

```
print_r ($collection->record->datafield[0]->subfield);
```

That doesn't seem to work. How do I account for the attributes?

Thanks!

Comment: Please read the manual first, before asking question. That is explained in the PHP manual under the headline "Examples": http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast to string when using `print_r()`:

```
<?php

$collection = simplexml_load_string('<collection xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
    <record>
        <datafield tag="010" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">96174405</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">(OCoLC)ocm34158924</subfield>
        </datafield>
    </record>
</collection>');

print_r( (string)$collection->record->datafield[0]->subfield );
```

The SimpleXML extension objects are created dynamically.

**Clarification:**

If you don't cast to string, `print_r()` will display this instead:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [code] => a
        )

    [0] => 96174405
)
```

Thus the recommendation.

Comment: Doesn't work with my code. I have $collection = simplexml_load_file('/file.xml')

Also, is there a way to reference the attributes to insure I'm accessing what I want to access?

Comment: If it doesn't work with your XML, then post your XML. It'd also be good to explain what "doesn't work" means for you.

Comment: Nevermind! I had a type. It does work. However, again is there a way to reference the attribute to insure I'm accessing the right field? Thanks!

Comment: What attribute? `code="a"`?

Comment: Yes, code="a" and tag="010". Thanks!

Comment: That's [example #5](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-5224)